WebStorm jasmin unit tests shows ESLint error that 'describe', 'it' etc' are undefined but then shows the correct documentation
In WebStorm, it shows me an ESLint error for all unit test files, that describe, it, etc are undefined, but then shows the correct documentation under it.

There is nothing special in the .eslint file. Changing the .eslint file, restarting WebStorm, invalidating WebStorm's cache all did not help.

Side note/FYI: "that describe, it, etc are undefined, but then shows the correct documentation under it. The ESLint error comes from ESLint integration while function definition/parameters from the IDE itself. I'm not using JS/TS but will ask anyway: will ESLint report the same issue for this file if you run it manually in your OS terminal?

Yes, the ESLint report does not show any error. I did not find any mention that, the there are there is an ESLint integration in the IDE but it would explain it..... Does this give you and idea how to fix it?

Fix? No idea. Set up - check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/eslint.html
